# Ssh choose no identity

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a ssh config file that has a `IdentityFile` entry.

So when I use `ssh`, this identity file is used, which is what I want.
However, if I want to temporarily disable this identity entry (without disabling other entries in the ssh config file), is there a way to do it directly from the ssh command line invocation, or do I have to comment out this line in the config file every time I want to remove the default identity?

Maybe something like `ssh -i /dev/null myserver`, although this one doesn't work due to file permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable public key authentication on command-line, which makes the client not to use any identity defined:

```
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no yourserver
```

Removing already added identities is not possible in the form how config file is made.